# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to open file

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x

I tried to open a file but kept getting an error (decoding error). I finally came across a topic on stackoverflow and got one step further. However, now I don't get any results when I try to loop through my file. The file is the setting file for uTorrent. I fairly new to Python and programming so I thought I could try to read and extract some parameters from that file.

```
getDir = r'{0}/{1}/{2}/AppData/Roaming/uTorrent/settings.dat'.format(partition, 
"Users", user)

data = []
try:
    with codecs.open(getDir, "r") as f:
        for lines in f:
            data.append(lines)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    pass
```

I get an error when I use UnicodeEncodeError but not with other exceptions. I have tried with/without codecs.open and to specify the decoding type in the open function, I have used ignore as well. The code goes through but the list remains empty.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1962: character maps to <undefined>
```

The code works fine with other files in the same directory. I have checked the file and there are some weird characters. Example below.

```
RÉ”  tÝï:Q‘æÐ†•
```

Really appreciate the help and thanks for a awesome site!

Comment: You are not specifying the targets encoding. Do you know which one is?

Comment: No, please tell me how I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary**

You would need to specify the encoding when you open the file.  It would look like this if the encoding is 'utf-16', though from the example you gave, it might not be.

```
with codecs.open(getDir, "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
```

**Error Handling**

You can also specify how you want to handle the errors by putting in the argument 'errors'.  This allows you to replace unknown characters or ignore them.  See here for more detail: http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes

**Additional Reading**

You're probably wondering how can you determine the encoding?  In summary, you need to be told what the encoding is.  Here's a link that describes encoding and decoding in a concise and understandable way: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html